# Clicking an image, getting the coordinates and saving them in a database JavaScript and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, save, coordinates

I have a little JS and rails problem. I am currently using this code to mark an image with a square:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function point_it(event){
    pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
    pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.left = (pos_x-1) ;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.top = (pos_y-15) ;
    document.getElementById("cross").style.visibility = "visible" ;
    document.pointform.form_x.value = pos_x;
    document.pointform.form_y.value = pos_y;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="pointform" method="post">
<div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" style = "background-image:url(<%= asset_path 'mamma.jpg' %>);width:900px;height:720px;">
<img src=<%= asset_path 'point.gif' %> id="cross" style="position:relative;visibility:hidden;z-index:2;"></div>
You pointed on x = <input type="text" name="form_x" size="4" /> - y = <input type="text" name="form_y" size="4" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

It works this way: There is a big picture (mamma.jpg) and when I click anywhere on this picture, the script will display the click-coordinates below in a textfield.
Additionally a square should appear on the picture where I clicked.

Now I have two problems:
1) The square just appears in the upper left corner of the picture, regardless where I click. Is there an easy fix for that?

2) I need to save the coordinates in a database and when I recall this page, the square should appear where I clicked last on the image. The image is part of a form (I use formtastic as well).

Now I know that Rails is server-sided and JS is client-sided and that I just can't let them communicate directly, but is there an easy fix also? Or do I have to grind through my controllers to make this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use an already available library to draw rectangle.

Try [JCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/) or http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Check the source code of [this](http://getspritexy.com) application, it generates x and y as well as width and height of a CSS sprite.

Comment: I don't want to crop something, I want to mark it, so unfortunately this won't help me :(

Comment: Thought it will be helpfull, will delete that.